# Visual Studio breaks when using curly braces instead of parenthesis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I have the following wrapper of std::make_unique:

```
template <typename Element, typename... ArgTypes>
auto makeUnique(ArgTypes&&... arguments) {
  return std::make_unique<Element>(std::forward<ArgTypes>(arguments)...);
}
```

which is used this way:

```
template <typename F>
static auto createCustomValidator(F &&validator) {
    auto func = [validator = std::forward<F>(validator)](const int val){ return validator(seconds(val)); };
    return makeUnique<property::CustomDoubleValidator<decltype(func)>>( std::move(func) );
}
```

Previous versions of Visual Studio accepted the following:

```
return makeUnique<property::CustomDoubleValidator<decltype(func)>>{ std::move(func) };
```

(notice the curly braces around std::move)

Visual Studio 16.5 breaks this and can only be fixed with parenthesis instead of curly braces. Which one is correct?

Comment: makeUnique<property::CustomDoubleValidator<decltype(func)>> is a function, so it must be called with parentheses

Comment: @sparik So VS was previously broken?

Comment: Yes. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: Since C ++ 11, we initialize an object from braced-init-list. I suggest you could refer to the Doc :[list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Comment: @sparik want to reply so I can award you the points?

Comment: I wrote an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeUnique<property::CustomDoubleValidator<decltype(func)>>` is a function, so it must be called with parentheses. The right answer is definitely parentheses.

It may be the case that previous versions of Visual Studio accepted curly braces as an extension.